# JMeter Throughput in Grafana Flux query language

Tags: jmeter, grafana, performance-testing, influxdb

Hi could anyone help me with the query I'd need to extract JMeter Throughput from Influx DB using the Flux query language please.

Basically this query but converted to Flux

```
SELECT mean("count") / $send_interval FROM "$measurement_name" WHERE ("transaction" = 'all' AND "application" =~ /^$application$/) AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)
```

Thanks in advance

I've tried several different ways but can't get it working.